# Is ContentProvider solution for DB-Activity architecture and/or Context leaking

Tags: android, multithreading, design-patterns, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

When using large database, in my case with approximately 20 DataSource definitions (2-5 tables for each DS, stored in same SQLiteDatabase), few problems comes up

For example:

- Thread synchronization ([ReentrantLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), [synchronization locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html))
- Singleton ([1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2i82mjoM46M), [2](http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/singletons-in-android/)) pattern for [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) subclass
- Possible [context leaking](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) on singleton for [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and/or DataSources

  - Or large memory heap if using Application's Context (`Context.getApplicationContext()`)

Notwithstanding I know, that using ContentProviders is not necessary when not exposing application's data to other services/applications ([1](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/), [2](http://vladnevzorov.com/2011/05/18/android-application-architecture-part-iii-main-parts-of-the-applications/)), i think it solves most of the above mentioned issues, and allows/pushes to implement interesting features such as [Broadcasts](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.cz/2008/03/observing-content.html) or usage of [Cursors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) to access data.

Is it just a misunderstanding of ContentProvider pattern, or is it really complex solution to possible, not only mentioned, issues?

Answer (score 2):

ContentProvider implementations can be a lot of boilerplate code to write which is why I developed Mechanoid DB. It might make your life easier if you plan to implement a sqlite backed content provider.

http://robotoworks.com/mechanoid-plugin/mechanoid-db/

http://robotoworks.com/2013/01/using-sqlite-in-android-with-mechanoid-db-part-1-tables/

Answer (score 1):

Given the recent deprecation of *startmanagingcursor* , and what you can read from the doc as well as from several books (including reto meyer's one), contentprovider seem to be the suggested approach to overcome a bunch of issues INCLUDING those you are listing.

Even if the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) states that *You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to share your data with other applications*, it seems clear that loaders based approach is strongly advertised AND relieves you from worrying about the issues you are just mentioned, not to mention that a loader can be automatically notified whenever your data changes.

Note alse that you can hide your content provider to the outside world adding

```
android:exported="false"
```

Thread synchronization *should* not be something to worry about in any case, since sqllite calls are thread safe (from what I remember).

I do also agree that writing a content provider includes a lot of boilerplate code, that's why I wrote a script to write that for me :-) . If you are interested, you can check it [here](https://github.com/fedepaol/Android-sql-lite-helper), but consider also that looking for "content provider generator" on google will return some decent if not better alternatives.